# Is fewer lines of code always better?

Tags: code-quality, clean-code, coding-style

Which of these programming styles is better?

```
var result = methodOne(methodTwo(a, methodThree(b)), c, d);
```

or

```
var result3 = methodThree(b);
var result2 = methodTwo(a, result3);
var result = methodOne(result2, c, d);
```

Comment: Definitely no, in most of case trying to make some code a one liner will kill the readability of the code.

Comment: why not `methodFour(var, var, var, var)`?

Comment: Replace lines of code with statements, and yes, it's always better.

Comment: For a bad example see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540673/fastest-way-to-increment-a-bitarray-binary-number-by-one). Clarity and maintainability should take precedence over arbitrary metrics: lines of code, keystrokes, vowels, ... . If performance requires something _clever_, aka _ugly_, then provide one or more comments explaining what is going on.

Comment: For the specific example given, I prefer the first because the intermediate variable names add absolutely no value.  Others have written excellent answers for the more general case.

Comment: Everything else being equal – **yes, fewer lines are *always* better**. But in your code (as in most), all else is *not* equal (see Michael Borgwardt’s answer).

Comment: Although this is rather a toy example, people have written pretty good answers for the general question behind it.

Comment: The long version is easier to step through with a debugger if need be.  Also easier to follow...

Comment: I think a real work example is needed. I don't like either samples. They both show poor design and abstraction. That being said, the only issue I have with the first sample is the difficulty in debugging.

Comment: So many people passed up an opportunity to reply with just "Yes."

Comment: I find the first version clearer, but that's mainly because of the example's artificially horrible method naming.

Comment: First one, just throw some whitespace in there, maybe a couple of comments to remind the reader what each argument is.

Comment: The second example looks an awful like like intermediate code written by a compiler that processed the first example. Just call the intermediate variables t1, t2, t3, ... Oh wait, you pretty much have: result1, result2, ...

Comment: in some programming languages `func(func2(d), func3(e));` doesn't imply that func2 is executed before func3. before readability comes correctness.

Comment: You should definitely read [Clean Code by Robert C. Martin](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=_i6bDeoCQzsC) and check the answers to [this related question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133404/what-is-the-ideal-length-of-a-method) to get an idea of how the length of code in lines relates to its readability.

Comment: Out of curiosity, don't compilers turn the first example into the second anyway?

Comment: In a dynamically typed language with the situation where `result2` and `result3` take a lot of memory, does the one-liner use less memory, or alternatively free up memory more quickly?

Comment: I went to school with a guy who claimed that "if it was hard to write, it should be hard to read." Don't be that guy.

Comment: The question itself is dangerous because it asks for a rule which fails to consider context.  Context is far more important than the rule.  If I were in a team where I was expected to write `max(a, abs(b))` in the long form, I would be looking for a new job where I could surround myself with more mature developers.  If I was frequently faced with `update_timer(a, toggle_io_and_return_prev(b))` I might start thinking about a new job with more disciplined developers.

Comment: `Always` is one 'red light' I normally use to find sentences that are inherently wrong. There're very few things that can truly be said to be `always`, and best practices aren't usually among them.

Comment: "Code should be as simple as possible but not simpler": Albert Einstein.

Comment: **Longer code is better** if your boss measures productivity in SLOC.

Comment: @mouviciel For that matter, why not `methodThree(b).methodTwo(a).methodOne(c,d);`?  Still one, still modular, more readable.

Comment: There is definitely a point at where more lines for the sake of more lines becomes bad. However, most of the time lines that do one thing will be easier to comprehend and debug. So I tend to write shorter simpler lines instead of combining statements into one.

Comment: Any statement that contains the words 'Always' is almost guaranteed to be incorrect.

Comment: I'm surprised so many agree that the second is easier to read, I definitely disagree at this level (just read inside out like you normally do).

Answer (score 220, accepted):

**In layman's words:**

The important thing is not the numbers of lines but the **readability** of the code.

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good
>   programmers write code that humans can understand. ([M. Fowler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler))

In the examples you gave, the second one is definitively easier to read.

Source code is for people to read.

Besides, intermediate values make the code easier to debug.

Code one-liners, on the other hand, are useful to show other people that you are *"smart"* and that you don't care.

Comment: +1, but be careful: more lines of code aren't always better either!

Comment: @JoachimSauer of course, as I said, the important thing is not number of lines.

Comment: In that specific example the first version is clearly more readable. Since the names of the variables don't give any additional information more lines just means that you have to search for the meaning of the parameters. But yes: In general more lines are often more readable.

Comment: this is just an example (not a great one I admit) to get my question across, the variable names shouldn't be taken in to account seeing as they are subject to each developer's naming convention

Comment: Well but the names are the central thing here. Start from [c = (a*b) + a]. [d=a*b, c=d+a] is not more readable. [tax=a*b, c = tax + a] is more readable. So if you can give the variable a meaningful name it can make sense to give it it's own line. If you have to invent a name where nobody knows what it actually represents you should just not introduce a new variable for that because what's the point in that case?

Comment: Not if your manager is judging your productivity by how many lines you write per day!  (Some still do, sadly...)

Comment: @Plankalkül The function already has a name, as well as the parameters it receives... so you don't have to really invent much when naming the variables.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller LOL

Comment: @user61852: If all you really do is putting result in front of the function name I would argue that the additional lines actually are useless because what it is will be apparent just by the method name.

Comment: @Plankalkül Remember ease of debugging that you get with intermediate values. That's important. Will you sacrifice that for what ? But you can do it the other way as long as it is legible and elegant.

Comment: The thing about the number of lines of code being "bad" is that long blocks of code are often caused by code repetition, which is always bad.  In the questioner's example, this is clearly not an issue, but it is good to look at files/classes/functions with many lines of code as a "bad code smell", and an indication that you should look for repetition.

Comment: Neither example is easy to read.  Something "real" would be nice.  Consider http://pastebin.com/BbttaD4R

Comment: It is absolutely ableist to say that the first is harder to read. Completely subjective as well. You can't remember that both commas and line feeds can separate variable definitions? As someone with poor eyesight, I cannot read code on a page that is off screen, that is literally impossible. The first example accommodates both people with good and poor eyesight.

Answer (score 105):

It depends, and your example is not useful in making the decision.

While fewer lines of code are not *always* better (at some point it leads to obfuscation), they *usually* are, simply because there's fewer things to keep track of when trying to understand the code.

In your specific example:

If the *names* of the intermediate values actually convey meaning that is not made obvious by the names of the methods and parameters used to compute those intermediate values, then they help in understanding the code.

However, if the names of the intermediate values do not add information, then they make the code harder to understand, since they're an additional state to keep track of. Even if they're immutable, they force you to consider whether they're used only once, or in different places.

Comment: +1 for _they force you to consider whether they're used only once, or in different places_. The first version clearly shows that the results from `methodThree` and `methodTwo` are used only at that place and nowhere else. So when reading the code the programmer can forget about them and focus only on `result`.

Comment: +1 for considering scope. If `methodThree ^ methodTwo` are only feeding `methodOne`, then great - why create extra variables that won't be re-used?

Comment: If `methodThree()` were something like `abs()` I would find the long version annoyingly verbose and distracting.  If it was a more complex function with side-effects or its purpose was not self-evident then naming its result or highlighting its action by giving it its own line might be more helpful.

Comment: I must admit that there is nothing more exciting in refractoring then reducing lines of code. I once brought down code from 1800 lines to 300 and intense delight I felt can't be described. :)

Comment: This was my first thought as well -- the biggest problem with both examples is the useless function and variable names, not the layout of the code.

Answer (score 67):

```
Code with as few lines as possible is definitely the best code and every semi-colon you see is basically the developer admitting they weren't clever enough to use advanced constructions like the comma operator or short-circuiting operators to keep the line going as long as possible like you can say `(x++ && false) || y += 2` instead of `x++; y += 2` and the first variant is just so much more concise and clearer as you can tell because it contains no semi-colons honestly I almost threw up writing the second one I mean who wants to use a character whose name contains a word related to your butt that's just dumb and anyways semi-colons introduce lots of vulnerabilities like what if you typed `while(true) ;` that would just keep running forever and so its clearly better to have no semi-colons to avoid problems like that overall I'd say programmer salaries should be inversely proportional to the number of newlines and semi-colons in their code because everyone knows as soon as you start using a metric like that it starts working even better than before you incentivized it
```

Comment: I edited your answer to fix your formatting before I got the joke.

Comment: Although this may not be a good answer, you still get my upvote lol

Comment: @Winston it's alright, it's still one giant run-on sentence and so it works. (For future readers: it used to use a code block so there was no word-wrap and you had to scroll).

Comment: your semi-colon => butt relation made me remember this: http://bash.org/?925050

Comment: How silly! First you are confusing lines with statements! And anyway the actual mesure should not be lines nor statements, but characters, as any golfer knows. It is also true that in most programming languages (not python) using more than one line is irrelevant, just remove line terminators.

Comment: To see @Strilanc's intended effect without reverting again see [his original version](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/203743/1).

Comment: @MarkHurd ohhhh, now I see what he did.  Removing the code blocks takes some of the sarcasm out of it.

Comment: You wrote the answer in one line. You are hired! Your next task is to write on programming best practices.

Comment: This must be the first answer ever that I voted up without even reading it.

Answer (score 35):

> Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring aircraft building progress by weight. (Bill Gates)

Of course, fewer lines are *not* always better. But in my experience, fewer lines are often better than more lines in terms of readability and maintainability. There are exceptions, of course, and your example might be one such exception.

Weight is needed to build an aircraft. But it should be in the right places.

Comment: @AndréParamés: Read Susan Lammers' [Programmers at Work](http://programmersatwork.wordpress.com/tag/susan-lammers/) and you'll get a pretty good idea of Gates' abilities as a programmer.  He was great at squeezing performance and space in 8-bit assembly language.  The last piece of code he wrote all by himself was the ROM BASIC for the TRS-80 Model 100, again in hand-optimized Z80 code.  His skills may be dated but there's no doubt he had them.

Comment: The Gates quote is about productivity, and doesn't really bear on this question much.  It's a response to those that measure "productivity" with something silly like "lines of code produced per hour" and is thus arguing against those who (implicitly) thing more lines of code is automatically better.

Comment: @AndréParamés: Even if Bill Gates was not a good programmer itself, he obviously knows how to lead a large group of programmers so that they create this kind of software he likes. Thus, I think one can conclude he knows how "good" software looks like.

Comment: @StevenBurnap His point is that everyone knows a lighter aircraft is better, but only if all other factors are identical. The analogy is easily as appropriate for on-going operational costs involved in both, as it is for progress during construction.

Answer (score 11):

In the first version, it is hard to see which parameters are passed to which method. So the second version is clearly better. In other cases however may not be that obvious.

The main difference of the second version is that it **allows you to name the intermediate values**. There may be cases where this name is crucial for understanding the code.

If however the intermediate values are anyway just called something like `varOne`, you may also just omit them by in-lining them.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you're using JavaScript, which changes the paramaters ever so slightly.

Unless you have a reason to store those `var`'s, you'd be better off not initalizing them at all.  But, you should make the single-statement version as readable as possible, by adding whitespace and a comment.

```
//Do X, Y, Z....
var result = methodOne(
    methodTwo(
        a, 
        methodThree(b)
    ), 
    c, 
    d
);
```

Comment: This could be made even clearer by using named parameters, for those languages that support them. (Unfortunately, JS isn't really one of them...)

Comment: @Bob You can easily use an object literal as a substitute for named parameters in JS

Answer (score 9):

**Is fewer lines of code always better?**

The short is simply **no**. The longer one, **no**, because **it depends**.

- How long is the code I want to shorten? If the code doesn't fit the screen, shortening it often makes it more readable
- How much is done in single line? If it's an access through 10 objects, it's surely good idea to split it to many lines
- What is better? Write long standard version or use single tricky syntax sugar or library function? How much people know that sugar/function? A great example are regular expressions. With single regex you can achieve as much as with many lines of code - but it sometimes takes hours to understand single regex. However, there are some regex that are widely used and google searchable.

**Which of these programming styles is better?**

Well, the second one is much much better in one aspect. If you need to debug what happens, you have the variables to inspect and more possibilities to place breakpoint.

On the other hand, I don't like using too much local variables, because I must invent the names for them. I hate such names as result1/2/3, because after some time I don't know which is for what. But I don't want to spend too much time on inventing the names... The first example is (for me) actually more readable because of bad variable names in second example.

Usually I start with the first code, and convert it to second first when I need to debug.

However, if the expressions are more complex, I prefer keeping intermediate results in local variables - but those local variable **must have self-explaining names**. Only then the code is easier to read.

Comment: agree with everything 100%, especially re inventing the names.

Answer (score 8):

My rule of thumb is to put each operation on its own line. This is especially helpful when stepping through code with the debugger. I also like assigning the result of an operation to a variable before passing it along so that I can break and examine its contents. so instead of

```
var result = methodOne(methodTwo(a, methodThree(b)), c, d);
```

I would go

```
var result3 = methodThree(b);
var result2 = methodTwo(a, result3);
var result = methodOne(result2, c, d);
```

If I'm not mistaken, the java and .Net JIT compilers would compile the two examples the same way.

alternatively, I would write a very detailed comment before the line explaining what it is I'm doing.

Comment: +1 for the observations that any modern compiler is going to optimize out the intermediate variables, so there's no performance penalty, and that the multiline version is easier to debug.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller: Each of those claims seems intuitively obvious, but, don't they sort of contradict each other? I mean, with Java (unlike, say, C++) there aren't usually separate "debug builds" and "release builds"; so if two programs differ in their debuggability, that must be because they were compiled differently. No?

Comment: @ruakh: No, because debuggers typically allow you to set a breakpoint on a particular line, but with no finer-grained control than that.  In Juann's example, if you are confident that `MethodThree` is working, but want to step into `MethodTwo` and examine the code that produces `result2`, you can set a breakpoint on the second line, run the program, and end up precisely at the problem area.  With the single-line version you could still set a breakpoint at that line, but you'd then have to step through the call to `MethodThree` to end up at the same place—a little more clumsy.

Comment: for debugging purposes, couldn't you use assertions inside each method to ensure the validity of the method's logic? (c.f. examining the variable that results, and then having to go back and examine the logic)

Comment: Sure, but if you write an assertion, you have yet another thing that may or may not have a bug.

Comment: +1 from me. Putting each operation on its own line really does pay dividends when it comes to debugging and it makes no difference to the runtime performance.

That is not an excuse for creating more code than is required of course, just that it is my experience in more than 20 years of coding that worshipping at the alter of less code (within a method) often leads to less debuggable code as sometime it is impossible to get a value for intermediary method return value due to those methods using the return value of methods as parameters to a method that is immediately returned.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect what everyone *wants* to hear is "no".

The fact of the matter is that your example isn't clear enough to give a solid answer.

**`resultThirdMethod` is a horrible name.** I find the first version **much** clearer than the second.

However, if you could give your variables names -- names that give more information than merely where the data came from -- then it could be better. It all depends on the actual situation.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular example I don't find the first version harder to read, it's just as reading a simple arithmetical expression such has `(a + f(b)) * c * d`. The second version doesn't add any information that helps to understand it (unless the variables have meaningful names that help to understand a complicated process).

What I feel a bit problematic with the second version is that it introduces additional complexity when analyzing the code. A programmer who reads the code needs to think about if `resultThirdMethod` or `resultSecondMethod` is used somewhere else then just to compute `result`. And if you write a method full of such statements there is no clear line of computation, you have to check constantly what is computed from what and where. So in this case, if you want the more verbose version, I'd suggest to either encapsulate it into a separate function:

```
function methodCombined(a, b, c, d) 
    var resultThirdMethod = methodThree(b);
    var resultSecondMethod = methodTwo(a, resultThirdMethod);
    return methodOne(resultSecondMethod, c, d);
}
// ...
result = methodCombined(a, b, c, d);
```

or at least enclose it into a code block so that the scope of variables is immediately visible:

```
var result;
{
    var resultThirdMethod = methodThree(b);
    var resultSecondMethod = methodTwo(a, resultThirdMethod);
    result = methodOne(resultSecondMethod, c, d);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how familiar the reader is likely to be with these operators and their problem domain. Even if all the methods are arithmetic functions, it can help to break it up.

Breaking up a larger formula into small steps can quite spoil the readability:

```
(let* ((term1 (* b b))
       (term2 (* 4 a c))
       (discriminant (- term1 term2))
       (twoa (* 2 a))
       (top1 (+ b (sqrt discriminant)))
       (top2 (- b (sqrt discriminant)))
       (root1 (/ top1 twoa))
       (root2 (/ top2 twoa)))
  (list root1 root2))
```

versus

```
(let* ((root1 (/ (+ b (sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))) 
                 (* 2 a))) 
       (root2 (/ (- b (sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c))))
                 (* 2 a)))
  (list root1 root2))
```

Breaking up formulas into small steps is what a compiler does when it generates intermediate code. (Fortran: FORmula TRANslator.)

Breaking up expressions for readability helps, but don't "Fortran it" (go overboard).

Comment: The lower version contains a repeated computation, namely `(sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))`. In this case I would prefer to have a variable holding the intermediate result. In case of recursive calls, using a variable to avoid repeated sub-expressions can make a big different with respect to complexity (linear versus exponential).

Comment: @Giorgio Any decent compiler does something called CSE (common subexpression elimination).

Comment: Although, it has to know that the functions used do not have side effects.

Comment: Which languages allow the compiler to determine that an expression has no side effects? I only know Haskell (maybe also Miranda and Clean).

Comment: @Giorgio C, Pascal, Fortran, Java, Algol, Lisp, Scheme, ...

Comment: In a language like C, you may call a function for its side effects not (only) for its result, so the compiler cannot eliminate common sub-expressions containing a function call because this could change the program's semantics. AFAIK you need referential transparency (like in Haskell) to safely eliminate common sub-expressions.

Comment: @Giorgio C compilers are able to analyze the functions that occur in the same translation unit, but obviously not external function calls. However, the latter can still be done with special language extensions. GCC has the "pure" attribute for this; please see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: The C language (minus the C preprocessor) has referential transparency because it is lexically scoped. Pointers can break referential transparency, but you have assurances such as if the address of a local variable is never taken, then it cannot be affected by a function call.

Answer (score 3):

Best style is the one which makes the code **most readable** (for a human, that is -- computers don't care). But "readable" depends *a lot* on **who does the reading** so that's context dependent. This is enough, though, to answer your exact question: "Is [whatever] *always* better" ? Then *no*, it depends on the context.

The first person who must read code is the developer himself. If you write code such that you will *yourself* be able to read and understand it four weeks from now, then you will have already done a good job -- a much better job than the majority of developers in the industry (alas).

One can add a few generalities, though. Reading code implies using the eye and brain. Human eyes tire faster when they have to move a lot, especially when they have to move vertically (lateral movement is less an issue). Using fewer lines of code, all other things being equal, will allow the reader to grasp the code with less vertical eye movement, so that's somewhat good.

On the other hand, the syntax analysis which goes in the brain will want to use as many "visual anchors" as possible, and will suffer from certain activities, in particular counting parentheses. Spreading the code over more lines, with indentation, helps the brain. It really is a trade-off between eye fatigue and brain fatigue, and, I insist, the right balance point is not the same for everybody.

Ultimately, it is a matter of "good taste". People who write ugly code are also people who are happy eating bad pizza.

Comment: +1 for "depends on who does the reading". I think we can see that in the answers here - some people like the variables, some people like the one-liner. Most answers here seem to be weighted by personal preference (though I particularly like Michael Borgwardt's answer involving scope). John Lubbock said, "what we see depends mainly on what we look for", and this is heavily influenced by our own experiences / background. So I really like your answer

Answer (score 0):

You give a bad example.

The solution you give to solve a problem better have a good design so it can be understandable, and good enough to keep the code short.

If you can make code that is more understandable by making it longer, it's something to do, but there is a limit.

I'll always think that code which have both a good design AND is kept short, ensures more understandability the shorter it is.

You should focus on a good design, and then find ways to make the code short enough so that people that will read it can understand it without making them scroll and scroll.

So to sum up, there is no real good answer to this, what is important is how well you divide your code into functions and sections, and how you can make it both short and easy to understand.

The bill gates quote is good, but there's also the quote that talk about a perfect piece of code, which is one where you can't take anything out.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those issues I think were you get to decide which way that works for each separate case. Deciding if a particular result should be stored in an intermediate variable is part of being a programmer, part of the craft. You use the skills you have acquired together with coding standards at your workplace.

In the two contrived examples below, I would probably go with 1A and 2A, because of readability (too much noise and redundancy in 1B, too long and indirect usage of an anonymous array in 2B). But you can't really come up with any exhaustive list of patterns where you can stipulate one way over the other - new situations arise all the time as the art of programming progresses.

```
1A:
startManufacture(loadProductName(), isProductOk(loadProductState()));

vs.

1B:
String productName = loadProductName();
ProductState state = loadProductState();
boolean productIsOk = isProductOk(state);
startManufacture(productName, productIsOk);


2A:
boolean antennaCount = storage.getCount(currentDealer, items[ANTENNA_INDEX]);
boolean chassisCount = storage.getCount(currentDealer, items[CHASSIS_INDEX], EXTERNAL_SHIPPING);
orderManufacture(RADIO, antennaCount, chassisCount);

vs.

2B:
orderManufacture(RADIO, storage.getCount(currentDealer, items[ANTENNA_INDEX]), storage.getCount(currentDealer, items[CHASSIS_INDEX], EXTERNAL_SHIPPING));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that both examples are equally *bad*, but that is just because of the insufficient example code. To be able to say if one of the two is better, you need to provide a real example.

There is absolutely no correlation between the number of source code lines, and the quality of the code.

Assuming that we disregard the obvious fact that the code needs to do what it is supposed to do, the most important aspect is that it is easily understood by the readers.

The "classic" way to accomplish this is to add code comments that describe the functionality of the code. In my personal experience, it is even better to use descriptive identifiers for methods, variables and constants.

If you for example see a source code sequence like this, you will immediately understand what it is supposed to do, and you can examine the individual methods and variables to (hopefully) just as easily determine that they do what they are supposed to do:

```
if (a_new_game_is_starting && hand_not_dealt_yet()) {
  deal_new_hand_to(all_players_at_table);
}
```

In the example above, there is no need to add any comments at all. What would a comment say that is not easily understood from the actual code? This is something to strive for - to *not need* to add comments to the code to describe what it does.

This is not something that is hard to do. All it requires is that you think about what you really are trying to accomplish, and name your identifiers from a functional point of view.

Answer (score 0):

More important than *readability* is *maintainability*, because the main reason we read code is to maintain it.
Maintaining often means making changes to the code because of small or large changes in requirements.

SO, think about what changes in requirements there might be, and try to make them as easy to do as possible. If you can lead the maintainer right to the relevant code, and let them make the changes with minimum editing, they will think you are a great programmer!

OTOH, if people are reading the code to verify its correctness, make sure your reasoning is clear as to why it is correct.
If people doubt the correctness of your code, they are likely to re-write it, which is likely to break it.
To prevent that, make sure the code explains itself.

Also, be sure to explain your performance-related decisions, because one way good code gets destroyed is by being re-written in a misguided attempt to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
return ($this->main->context != "ajax" || in_array($this->type, $this->definition->ajax)) ? eval('return method_exists($this,"Show'.ucfirst($this->type).'") ? $this->Show'.ucfirst($this->type).'('.(count($args) ? join(",",array_map(create_function('$a','return (is_numeric($a) || preg_match("/^array/",$a)) ? $a : "\"".$a."\"";'),$args)) : "").') : null;') : '';
```

I bumped into this code on a project I inherited some time ago. I think it nicely demonstrates why it is a bad idea to try and use as few lines as possible. It's completely unreadable and impossible to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling things out can help not only with readability but also writability.

This might seem like a silly interview question but I was asked once in an interview to write a function to rotate an image 90 degrees. The source and destination are provided (you don't need to do any memory allocation) and the width and height of the source. Yes, it's an easy problem. I suggest you do it before continuing and see if you have any trouble.

.

Did you? Did you test it? Since I was asked the question in an interview I used the question in interviews as well and what I found was many programmers would get confused. They'd write code like this

```
 void Rotate90(const Pixel* src, Pixel* dst, int width, int height) 
 {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) 
    {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) 
      {
         dst[???] = src[???];
```

And that's where they would get stuck. They would spend sometimes as much as 20 minutes on the whiteboard trying to figure out what goes in those ??? area. Lots of times they'd think they have the answer and write things like

```
         dst[x * width + (height - 1 - y)] = src[y * width + x];
```

getting the fact that using `width` with `dst` is wrong. Or often they'd get the `x` and `y` mixed up in one side or the other.

The problem is that `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` all swap meaning because when rotating 90 degrees the destination becomes width tall and height wide which makes referring to those variables confusing. I always wished a programmer would add some more variables to help make it clearer for themselves, like this

```
 void Rotate90(const Pixel* src, Pixel* dst, int src_width, int src_height)
 {
   int dst_width = src_height;
   int dst_height = src_width;

   for (int src_y = 0; src_y < src_height; ++src_y) 
   {
     for (int src_x = 0; src_y < src_width; ++src_x) 
     {
       int dst_x = src_height - src_y - 1;
       int dst_y = src_x;
       dst[dst_y * dst_width + dst_x] = src[src_y * src_width + src_x];
     }
   }
 }
```

It seemed to me breaking things out into their explicit meanings would make it far easier to write the code and far easier to avoid mistakes. I felt like if I saw a programmer do this I'd think of them as *wise* and rate them higher.

Yes there are a few optimizations you can make. That's not the point. Yes, the math inside the last statement could also be broken out into separate lines. That would be fine as well. The point is, adding more lines made it easier to understand for the person writing the code, not just a person reading it later. In this case because the meaning of `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` are different in relation to `dst` vs `src` making separate variables for each makes the code far clearer to read **AND write**.

Continuing...similarly it's often useful to be able to inspect values before a function is called, especially if it's a function in a library or the system that you can't step into. If you write code like this

```
ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(angle) * radius, y + Math.sin(angle) * radius);
```

vs this

```
var circleX = x + Math.cos(angle) * radius;
var circleY = y + Math.sin(angle) * radius;
ctx.lineTo(circleX, circleY);
```

In the second style you can now stop the debugger at the `ctx.lineTo` line and inspect `circleX` and `circleY`. You might find they are `NaN` which would probably get you to check that `x`, `angle`, and `radius` are actually the correct names, something you wouldn't be able to do in the debugger. ("strict" mode probably catches that). It also allows you to easy log the values

```
console.log("cx: " + circleX = ", cy: " + circleY);
```

Yet another example,

```
class Person 
{
public:
   ...
   const String& name() const { return m_name; }
   int age() const { return m_age; }

private:
   string m_name;
   int m_age;
};
```

vs

```
class Person 
{
public:
   ...
   const String& name() const 
   { 
     return m_name; 
   }

   int age() const 
   { 
     return m_age; 
   }

private:
   string m_name;
   int m_age;
};
```

I know some of you will scream at this example because your personal style wants getters and setters to be 1 line but hear me out ... when debugging, depending on the debugger, in the first style if you put a breakpoint on `age` or `name` the debugger will not be able to inspect `this` nor `m_age` nor `m_name` so you'll have no way to checking before the function returns what it's going to return or what object it's referencing. In the second style you can put breakpoints on the `return` lines and you'll be able to inspect everything.

The point of this answer is that more lines is often not only good for readability. It's also often good for writability and for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

No.

In fact, I'd go further and say fewer lines of code are rarely better.

Now, that's not to say don't encapsulate method calls etc but in your example above, when debugging - it's going be very hard to see the outcome of the methodThree and methodTwo when it's all inlined like that.

Lots of code in a method doing lots of things is bad. Lots of small methods that get called and assign to local variables enhance readability, enhance maintainability and have no real cost as the compiler will happily optimise away.

Comment: +1 This is a pretty decent answer and I wonder why it was downvoted.

Comment: +1. I agree w/ JonathanHobbs. "rarely better", definitely. And "..encapsulate.." touches on why. @sh1 comment said "context is far more important than the rule". I will try to fuse these two ideas by saying what is the code trying to _express_? What is its _intent_?

Answer (score -1):

Think from basics.
Why we write code, when we want to add some functionality and hand it over to another developer, can he understand your code or not, why it's important to structure, why should one follow basic standard guidelines?

The answers are as follows:

Why we put comments in our code.
For developers (who can take advantage of this small documentation to understand the code and routine functionality), computers or decoding/encoding systems just bypass comments, and only deal with the actual code. For example:development bundle and minifest version,

If we use second option it's easy to read and extend and not much guidance is needed by a new developer extending our code.
But if we use first option which is less documented only the person who wrote this code or can understand its purpose, and not the entire team. We are working on rapid development cycle where we need to work on different project and don't have much time to get co-ordinate with other departments, so in this case the second approach works well and another developer can easily extend functionality. It's all about dependency: we work on modularization of code where thousands of developers work on thousands of function and they know only what to return, what to pass to function and which variable is assigned to what, and *for* what.

For single user or small programs the first approach is ok when team are working together but when people are working remotely what to do, thats the point you likely to go with second option, optimization is another technique to shorten the code but only after we are happy with output.

computer is machine , only understand zero and one's language , but if we write code who itself guide other developer about programe like second approach , new people can also use this as guidance or to edit the program ,

computer understand 0 and 1 and human can understand comments 

so i like second approach which help developer to understand whats going on inside loop or function 

**eg:**suppose if you are working on some project and you use 1st way and at some case you had another task and another developer is working on your code , does he understand this or not? its not question about simplicity or how to document , its all about **how to farward our code to our partner when he want to update the code with hassle free support.**

**second approach is well for partners and developers and 1st options work well when we are working on web platform , or writting script where size of the code matters**

TL;DR:
**Document your code**. Write comments when you're writing it. It will save you valuable time three months down the line when you come back to it and can't understand what the code is doing. Also, your co-workers will sing praises of you when they can actually understand what you're doing, and are easily able to extend/refactor or otherwise modify code written by you. 
Don't [overdo it](http://andrevanderschyff.za.net/?p=35), however.

If fewer lines of code make sense, go ahead and do it in that many lines. But do **not** make it so that typing fewer lines would make you have to add comments to explain your code. It should be as self-explanatory as possible.

Comment: This answer is poorly formatted. Please consider editing it to make it more readable.

Comment: I don't agree that either of these are necessarily either well- or poorly- documented. In version 2, a sensible variable name might help describe the method, but then again so would a doc-string inside the method itself. Either way, there are a series of transformations here that would be best expressed in a sentence before-hand, i.e. "Need to determine X (output of methodOne), where X is dependent on Y (methodTwo) and Z (methodThree).

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
var result = methodOne(   methodTwo(    a, 
                                        methodThree(b)
                                   ),
                          c,
                          d
                      );
```

This will probably be even further improved by the help of a decend IDE, printing lines that match the braces.

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell, the human brain,*for most common people*, can hold 7 different things at best. This is for common people, and this is an average. (I'm afraid I haven't found the source of my statement)

As a consequence, if you want to write code that anyone can read, it should not use more than 7 differents variables/concepts/functions/operations.

for example:

```
rotate(translate(rotate(translate(circle,50,0),0,10,pi),-50,0),0,10,pi)
```

there it is really hard to understand what is going on, astonishingly this lines does absolutely nothing in the geometric sense:

```
circle = translate(circle,50,0)
circle = rotate(circle,0,10,pi)
circle = translate(circle,-50,0)
circle = rotate(circle,0,10,-pi)
```

this is also why it is easier to read functions that are less than 40 lines of code too.

Answer (score -2):

Both examples are actually bad.

What happens if methodOne fails?  What happens if methodTwo fails?  What happens if methodThree fails?  You obviously omitted the error checking for clarity here, but it is an important point - adding error checking will add more lines of code (which on it's own should answer your question) so extra lines of *meaningful* code that actually *does something* should never be viewed as a bad thing.

Aside from that, I would still favour the second example.  The reason why is because it's more maintainable; you can more easily insert a call to methodTwoPointFive between the calls to methodTwo and methodThree, for example, should future requirements need it.

Comment: Sigh - more drive-by downvoting.  If somebody wants to be constructive about it then they should at least leave a comment.

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but I'm guessing it's because error checking would be beside the point here: we're assuming we don't need to check for it in this circumstance. I get you're making a separate point that error-checking adding lines of code itself hints that extra lines of code are fine, but in your first sentences you appear to suggest (for argument's sake, I understand) that these statements should be split up and wrapped in their own try/catch blocks or be checked for failure. But there's no call for it here necessarily. That's massive over-engineering!

Comment: @JonathanHobbs: and just as importantly, what if you can't recover at that level -- in that case, there's no point in determining what fails, as that will be some other piece of codes responsibility to handle.